# How to draw two diameters of a circle in `TikZ`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

This is the block diagram I'm trying to draw using the `TiKz` package.
[image: Diagram Picture]

Here is the code I have used but I don't know how I can put the `\times` like shape in the circles and make the circles a little larger. Can you help?

My code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
% Definition of blocks:
\tikzset{%
  block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 3em,
    minimum width = 3em},
  sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, % Adder
  input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
  output/.style   = {coordinate} % Output
}
% Defining string as labels of certain blocks.
        \tikzset{%
    block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 3em,
        minimum width = 3em},
    sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, % Adder
    input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
    output/.style   = {coordinate} % Output
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\draw
node at (0,0) [input, name=input1] {} 
node [sum, right of=input1] (suma1) {}
node at (5,0) [block] (G) {$\mathbf{G}(s)$}
node at (8,0) [output,name = output1con]{}
node [block, below of=G] (K) {$\mathbf{K}(s)$}
node[sum,below of=output1con](suma2){}
node [output, right of=output1con](output1){}
node [output,below of=input1](output2){}
node [input, below of=output1](input2){}
;
% Joining blocks. 
% Commands \draw with options like [->] must be written individually
\draw[->](input1) -- node[near start] {$\mathbf{u}_1(s)$}(suma1)
node[near end,below]{$+$}(suma1);
\draw[->](suma1) -- node {$\mathbf{e}_1(s)$} (G);
\draw[->](G) -- node{}(output1con) -- node[] {}(output1);
\draw[->](output1con) -- node[right,near end]{$+$}(suma2);
\draw[->](K) -| node[near end,above=4mm,left]{$+$} (suma1); 
\draw[->](suma2) -- node[above]{$\mathbf{e}_2(s)$}(K);
\draw[->](K)--node[]{}(output2);
\draw[->](input2) -- node[right=3mm, above]{$\mathbf{u}_2(s)$}(suma2) 
node[near end, above]{$+$}(suma2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My end results:
[image: End results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15160/draw-a-circle-node-with-a-cross-symbol-inside-it-to-resemble-a-multiplier-of-a-s) to draw a circle with a cross and using the `minimum size` option, this would be one way to get the figure:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt,border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
% Definition of blocks:
\tikzset{%
  block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 3em,
    minimum width = 3em},
  sum/.style      = {draw, circle, node distance = 2cm}, % Adder
  input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
  output/.style   = {coordinate} % Output
}
% Defining string as labels of certain blocks.
        \tikzset{%
    block/.style    = {draw, thick, rectangle, minimum height = 3em,
        minimum width = 3em},
    cross/.style={path picture={ 
            \draw[black]
            (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west) (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
    }},
    sum/.style      = {draw, circle, cross, node distance = 2cm, minimum size = 3ex}, % Adder
    input/.style    = {coordinate}, % Input
    output/.style   = {coordinate} % Output
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick, node distance=2cm, >=triangle 45]
\draw
node at (0,0) [input, name=input1] {} 
node [sum, right of=input1] (suma1) {}
node at (5,0) [block] (G) {$\mathbf{G}(s)$}
node at (8,0) [output,name = output1con]{}
node [block, below of=G] (K) {$\mathbf{K}(s)$}
node[sum,below of=output1con](suma2){}
node [output, right of=output1con](output1){}
node [output,below of=input1](output2){}
node [input, below of=output1](input2){}
;
% Joining blocks. 
% Commands \draw with options like [->] must be written individually
\draw[->](input1) -- node[near start] {$\mathbf{u}_1(s)$}(suma1)
node[near end,below]{$+$}(suma1);
\draw[->](suma1) -- node {$\mathbf{e}_1(s)$} (G);
\draw[->](G) -- node{}(output1con) -- node[] {}(output1);
\draw[->](output1con) -- node[right,near end]{$+$}(suma2);
\draw[->](K) -| node[near end,above=4mm,left]{$+$} (suma1); 
\draw[->](suma2) -- node[above]{$\mathbf{e}_2(s)$}(K);
\draw[->](K)--node[]{}(output2);
\draw[->](input2) -- node[right=3mm, above]{$\mathbf{u}_2(s)$}(suma2) 
node[near end, above]{$+$}(suma2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, This works marvelously. cheers.