# How to make suncross with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

My question is on the title. I want to make arrow pointing at suncross like [this](https://ibb.co/TK511Lm)? I can make the arrow by myself can you help me to make the suncross?

Comment: @Marijn yes thanks!

Comment: Why don't you simply use `$\boldsymbol{\otimes}$`?

Comment: Oh wait. I got many errors.

Comment: @Bernard cz i need to adjust the shape. The linewidth, the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Draw a circle node with a cross symbol inside it to resemble a multiplier of a signal modulator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15160/draw-a-circle-node-with-a-cross-symbol-inside-it-to-resemble-a-multiplier-of-a-s)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[cross/.style={path picture={ 
                \draw[black,line width=1pt]
                (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding 
        box.north west) (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture 
          bounding box.north east);
        }}]
        
        \node [draw,circle,cross,minimum width=1 cm,line width=1pt](B) at (3,0){}; 
        \draw[<-,line width=1pt,stealth-] (B.south 
        west)to[out=225,in=75,looseness=1.3]($(B.south)+(-3,-6)$);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Finally, thanks you so much.